# Dynamically add column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have following data in table.

```
State   P_Name     Product    Apr-2013  May-2013   Jun-2013   July-2013   Aug-2013   Sep-2013   Oct-2013   Nov-2013   Dec-2013   Jan-2014   Feb-2014   Mar-2014
===============================================================================================================================================================
s1      p1         pro1        1500      4587        5245      6541        9683       45878      65464      4444       4411       21452       223322    232322
s1      p1         pro2        1500      4587        5245      6541        9683       45878      65464      4444       4411       21452       223322    232322
```

Now first three columns are static but values are dynamic and remaining column_names and values are dynamic. With this there is a variable

```
Declare @MONTHS INT
SET @MONTHS = 1--3/6/12 can be 1/3/6/12 as monthly/quater/half-year/fullyear
```

Now depending on values of `@MONTHS` i have to add values to first/first-to-third/first-to-six/first-to-twelve column and display only that columns.
IF

```
SET @MONTHS = 1
```

then above data is result. but

```
SET @MONTHS = 3
```

then the desired result is as follows:

```
State   P_Name     Product    Jun-2013   Sep-2013   Dec-2013   Mar-2014
=======================================================================
s1      p1         pro1        11332      62102      74319       477096
s1      p1         pro2        11332      62102      74319       477096
```

Here only 3rd month column is displayed with addition of apr-2013,may-2013 and jun-2013 column values( in jun-2013 column), same i want for 6 and 12 also in 6th and 12th column.
The no of month-columns and no of rows are dynamic.
The no of month-columns can be in multiple of 1/3/6/12 only.
Need help in this.
Thanks.

***EDIT:***
Above table data is derived with another table with help of PIVOT. Is it possible before/with PIVOT without loop..?
Below is data before PIVOT.

```
state   p_name   product   amount   monthnames
================================================
s1      p1       pro1      1500     apr-2013
s1      p1       pro1      4587     may-2013
s1      p1       pro1      5245     jun-2013
and so on................
........................
```

Comment: Show us what you already have.

Comment: not getting any idea for this...:(sorry for important information edited after some time....!!

Comment: One of the site rules here: "*Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected result.*"  So at least show us what you've got for the static parts.  Then when can change it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Think this will do it. Adding a column name for the derived columns might be a little tricky, but I think it's possible. Also needs some exception handling if the column count is not a multiple of `@month`. I called my table `States`.

```
declare @month int
set @month = 3

declare cur cursor for 
select name
  from syscolumns
 where object_name(id) = 'States'
   and colorder > 3
 order by colorder

declare @count int, @col varchar(100), @sql varchar(max), @tmp varchar(max)

set @count = 1
set @sql = 'select State, P_Name, Product, 0'
set @tmp = ''

open cur
fetch cur into @col
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
    set @tmp = @tmp + '+' + @col
    if @count = @month begin
        set @sql = @sql + @tmp + ', 0'
        set @tmp = ''
        set @count = 0
    end

    set @count = @count + 1

    fetch cur into @col
end

set @sql = substring(@sql, 1, len(@sql) - 3) + ' from States'

exec(@sql)

close cur
deallocate cur
```